# tkinter in operations with arrays?

Tags: arrays, tkinter, sum

I want to sum two arrays with tkinter but something does not work with the arrays.

```
 def ApplytoLabel():/*
        xx=size.get()
        for i in range(xx):
            element = box_list[i].get() # Get value from corresponding Entry
            ArrayLabel=Label(root,text="Array1 Element "+element)
            box_list.append(element)
            ArrayLabel.pack()

        for i in range(xx):
            element = box_list1[i].get() # Get value from corresponding Entry
            ArrayLabel=Label(root,text="Array2 Element  "+element)
            box_list1.append(element)
            ArrayLabel.pack()

        box_list = []   # Create list of Entrys
    def Boxes():
        xx=size.get()
        for i in range(0,xx):        
            box=Entry(root)
            box_list.append(box)
            box.pack()
            # Append current Entry to list
        ApplytoLabel1=Button(root,text="Submit To Array",command=ApplytoLabel)
        ApplytoLabel1.pack()
    box_list1=[]

    def Boxes1():
        xx=size.get()
        for i in range(0,xx):        
            box=Entry(root)
            box_list1.append(box)    # Append current Entry to list
            box.pack()
        ApplytoLabel1=Button(root,text="Submit To Array",command=ApplytoLabel)
        ApplytoLabel1.pack()

    tot_sum_array = []    

    def sum(box_list,box_list1,tot_sum_array):
        for j in range (xx):
            #ArrayLabel.pack()
            suma=(int(box_list[j])+int(box_list1[j]))
            tot_sum_array.append(suma)
        sum2=Label(root,text='result'%tot_sum_array).grid(row=1,column=5)

    Array = Frame(root)
    Array.pack()

    text1=Label(Array,text="Enter the Size of Array:",
                   font="Arial 10 bold",fg="blue")
    text1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="w")

    size=IntVar()

    ArraySize=Entry(Array,textvariable=size)
    ArraySize.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="w")

    SizeofArray=Button(Array,text="Submit",command=Boxes)
    SizeofArray.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky="w")

    SizeofArray=Button(Array,text="Submit1",command=Boxes1)
    SizeofArray.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky="w")

    sum1=Button(Array,text='sum',command=sum)
    sum1.grid(row=0,column=4,sticky="w")

root.mainloop()/*
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things:

Pay attention to the code indentation. This code does not run without fixing. We check it by pasting it into IDLE (or other) and running it to see whats the matter.

There is a built-in function called `sum`. If you give that name to your function you will not be able to call the built-in `sum` function. I renamed it `sum_array`.

You define the function sum_array to accept three arguments, but you call from a Button without arguments:

```
def sum(box_list,box_list1,tot_sum_array):

sum1 = Button(Array, text='sum', command=sum)
```

As all arguments were in the global namespace I just took them out of the function defenition.

Each time you click on any of the "submit" buttons you create a new array which is appended to the respective arrays, `box_list` and `box_list1`, and also new entries for those elements.

You missed to use `.get()` in the `sum` function:

```
suma=(int(box_list[j])+int(box_list1[j]))
```

should be:

```
suma = int(box_list[j].get())+int(box_list1[j].get())
```

Assuming you wanted a element by element listing of the sum, I changed the `sum` function to print that.

I'm not quite sure about the function of the button "Submit To Array", as the program only reads the Entrys when the sum is calculated.

Is this how you would like it to work:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def ApplytoLabel():
    xx = size.get()
    for i in range(xx):
        element = box_list[i].get() # Get value from corresponding Entry
        ArrayLabel = Label(root, text="Array1 Element "+element)
        box_list.append(element)
        ArrayLabel.pack()

    for i in range(xx):
        element = box_list1[i].get() # Get value from corresponding Entry
        ArrayLabel = Label(root, text="Array2 Element  "+element)
        box_list1.append(element)
        ArrayLabel.pack()

box_list = []   # Create list of Entrys

def Boxes():
    xx = size.get()
    for i in range(xx):        
        box = Entry(root)
        box_list.append(box)
        box.pack()
        # Append current Entry to list
    ApplytoLabel1 = Button(root, text="Submit To Array", command=ApplytoLabel)
    ApplytoLabel1.pack()

box_list1 = []

def Boxes1():
    xx = size.get()
    for i in range(xx):        
        box = Entry(root)
        box_list1.append(box)    # Append current Entry to list
        box.pack()
    ApplytoLabel1 = Button(root, text="Submit To Array", command=ApplytoLabel)
    ApplytoLabel1.pack()

tot_sum_array = []    

def sum_array():    # Changed name from "sum", removed argument list
    xx = size.get()
    sum2 = Label(root, text='result'%tot_sum_array).pack()
    for j in range(xx):
        # Added ".get()" to the calculation
        suma = int(box_list[j].get())+int(box_list1[j].get())
        tot_sum_array.append(suma)
        Label(root, text=str(suma)).pack()

Array = Frame(root, bg='thistle')
Array.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

text1 = Label(Array, text="Enter the Size of Array:", font="Arial 10 bold", fg="blue")
text1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")

size = IntVar()
ArraySize = Entry(Array, textvariable=size)
ArraySize.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")

SizeofArray = Button(Array, text="Submit", command=Boxes)
SizeofArray.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="w")

SizeofArray = Button(Array, text="Submit1", command=Boxes1)
SizeofArray.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="w")

sum1 = Button(Array, text='sum', command=sum_array)
sum1.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky="w")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
labels = []
label = tk.Entry(rframe)
for i in range(8):
    label = tk.Label(rframe, text=f'label{i}')
    labels.append(label)
```

then pack() before .mainloop()

Answer (score -1):

```
Finally, I did it. It is very basic but it took me hours...

from tkinter import*

root=Tk()
root.title("Looping of entry box")
root.geometry("1200x600")

def ApplytoLabel():
    xx=size.get()

    for i in range(xx):
        element = box_list[i].get() # Get value from corresponding Entry
        ArrayLabel=Label(root,text="Array1 Element: "+element)

        box_list.append(element)
        ArrayLabel.pack()

    for i in range(xx):
        element = box_list1[i].get() # Get value from corresponding Entry
        ArrayLabel=Label(root,text="Array2 Element: "+element)
        box_list1.append(element)
        ArrayLabel.pack()
    for i in range(xx):
        sum_ele= (int(box_list[i].get())+ int(box_list1[i].get()))
        Arraysum=Label(root,text=sum_ele)
        tot_sum_array.append(sum_ele)
        Arraysum.pack()

box_list = []   # Create list of Entrys
def Boxes():
    xx=size.get()
    for i in range(xx):        
        box=Entry(root)
        box_list.append(box)    # Append current Entry to list
        box.pack()
    ApplytoLabel1=Button(root,text="Submit To Array",command=ApplytoLabel)
    ApplytoLabel1.pack()

box_list1=[]
def Boxes1():
    xx=size.get()
    for i in range(xx):        
        box1=Entry(root)
        box_list1.append(box1)  
        box1.pack()    # Append current Entry to list
    ApplytoLabel1=Button(root,text="Submit To Array",command=ApplytoLabel)
    ApplytoLabel1.pack()

tot_sum_array=[]
def sum():
    xx=size.get()
    for i in range (xx):
        suma=Entry(root).pack()
        tot_sum_array.append(suma)
        suma.pack()

Array = Frame(root)
Array.pack()

text1=Label(Array,text="Enter the Size of Array:",
               font="Arial 10 bold",fg="blue")
text1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="w")

size=IntVar()
suma=IntVar()

ArraySize=Entry(Array,textvariable=size)
ArraySize.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="w")

SizeofArray=Button(Array,text="Submit array#1",command=Boxes)
SizeofArray.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky="w")

SizeofArray=Button(Array,text="Submit array#2",command=Boxes1)
SizeofArray.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky="w")



enter code here
```

root.mainloop()`enter code here`